# In 30:4, Surah Al-Rum Ayah 4, why does بضع is translated to "three to nine"

Tags: quran, arabic, quran-translation, arabic-translation, ayah

In [30:4](https://quran.com/30/4), Surah Al-Rum Ayah 4, the word بضع is translated to "three to nine" in Saheeh International.

> Within **three to nine** years. To Allah belongs the command [i.e.,
> decree] before and after. And that day the believers will rejoice

The word seems to mean "a few". I want to know the basis of translating it to "three to nine", with primary sources.

Comment: In the given case one should ask the translator(s) this is not a translation that is agreed upon. But it could be one of the options that was mentioned in tafsir. However IMHO here the translators went too far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This word in Arabic means "a few" . But in order for the audience to understand more, they explain to non-Arabs that these few days or years mean a number between three and nine. About three to nine years. Or about three to nine days.

https://corpus.quran.com/wordbyword.jsp?chapter=30&verse=4
https://www.almaany.com/en/dict/ar-en/%D8%A8%D8%B6%D8%B9/